# updating a textField based on changing a slider in the javaFX

Tags: javafx-8

I am not professional in javaFX. I want to see the recent changes of a slider in the textField. but it doesn't work. I desperately need help.

```
slider1.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number oldValue, Number newValue) 
  {     
    textField.setText(newValue.doubleValue().toString());

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textfield.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));
```

Answer (score 2):

`newValue.doubleValue()` returns `double` (which is a primitive type) not `Double` (class). therefore `newValue.doubleValue().toString()` doesn't exist.

Change

```
 textField.setText(newValue.doubleValue().toString());
```

to

```
 textField.setText(newValue.toString());
```

As an alternative, you can use binding instead of `ChangeListener`:

```
   textField.textProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty().asString("%.2f"));
```